Auto tweeting activity
Was I wrong that I saw a banner/notice somewhere for a user to setup auto-tweeting of their activity on Bitcoin.SE to their Twiter account?
Where can this be setup (or was I seeing this on another site somewhere)?

Activity is auto-tweeted on this account: https://twitter.com/stackbitcoin

The newest tweet is May 7, 2013. I was, in any case, referring to user-specific functionality, which I probably did not make clear enough.

It looks like what you were referring to is now on https://twitter.com/stackbitcoin

Oh apologies yes, @stackbitcoin
